# Windows form : Cannot set a new value for a property in design mode from a custom selection form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, uitypeeditor

I created a user control in .NET framework/C# that has a property called User from a type UserModel. UserModel is a simple class with a string for the name and an integer for the age.

Code of UserModel class :

```
[Serializable]
[ComVisible(true)]
[TypeConverter(typeof(UserTypeConverter))]
[Editor(typeof(UserTypeEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]

public class UserModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public UserModel(string name, int age) 
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }

    public override string ToString() { return Name; }

}
```

code of the user control  :

```
public partial class UserManagement: UserControl
{
    private UserModel _userModel = new UserModel("DefaultName", 0);

    [Category("Behavior"), Description("Instance of a user model")]
    public UserModel User
    {
        get
        { 
            return _userModel;
        }
        set
        {
            _userModel = value;
        }
    }                

    public UserManagement()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

When I want to set new values for my User property. I open a new form with a custom type editor and a custom type selector to select the name and the age of the user. Here is the form open :

[image: User selection form]

Everything is working until now. I want my value to be saved as `this.userManagement1.User = new UserModel("newName","newAge");` in the designer.cs of my form.
But when I click on OK to valid my modifications I can see my new values in the return value of my form/type selector but my setter method of the property is never called. Which means my new value is not saved in the designer.cs file . So when I close and reopen my form the value is not saved.

If you want to test a project, here is a link to download the solution : [link to the project](https://www.transfernow.net/dl/20230210RFvPXms4)

Has everyone ever experienced something like that and know how to solve this problem.

PS : This project is just to show a simple representation of what happened in a more complex project

Comment: You should apply the [ShouldSerialize()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/defining-default-values-with-the-shouldserialize-and-reset-methods?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) and `Reset` methods for the `User` property.

Comment: The designer has no way to find out that calling that constructor also gets the properties set to their desired value.  Reflection doesn't work that way.  So that's not what it does.  Find the object back in the form's .resx file.  De/serialized by binary serialization, which assigns properties without using their property accessors.  To get it the way you want you need a custom CodeDomSerializer.

Comment: Since you want to see this: `this.userManagement1.User = new UserModel("newName","newAge");` as the serialized value of a Property, you are probably using the `InstanceDescriptor` of the TypeConverter. In that case, you have to add `[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]` to the Property. BUT, the Property is only serialized when the value of the Type (`UserModel`) is read again, when the default serializer kicks in (e.g., you change the Layout of the UserControl, moving it around)

Comment: As Hans, mentioned, you need a custom serializer (CodeDomSerializer), or move the Attributes to the Property instead of the Type. Then the value is stored as a Resource and serialized each time. In this case, you cannot see the actual value in the Designer's file -- Note also (may be useful to mention) that the UITypeEditor must return the actual Type, not `Object`, not a `dynamic` cast or anything else